# How can I get a list of all preprocessor symbols used (or defined) within a file?

Tags: unix, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a number of **C**/C++ project files. I'd like to know the full list of preprocessor symbols used by the files. Is there a flag to gcc, or is there some tool I can use to get this list.

Optionally, if the tool also told me the list of symbols defined by the file, that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `gcc -E -dM <file_list>` - preprocess, then output #defines.

My gcc is a tad rusty, so I'm not sure whether or not you explicitly need the -E, but try both?

For further reference, see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

Comment: Not to be a pest, but could I trouble you to mark this as the correct answer? This way it shows up as answered for others who might have the same problem!